# How to iterate over a date range in PL/SQL select

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

Hi Thank you for considering to look at my problem, However I am trying to figure out to iterate over a date range in select statement

Basically select statement gives the result if a job is open at certain date. We would like iterate over dates and find count number of job openings on each day.

```
 declare
   dfrom date;
   dtill date;
   AB date;
   begin
      dfrom := TO_DATE('2022-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      dtill := TO_DATE('2022-09-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      AB := dfrom;

    SELECT COUNT(A.ID) AS cnt
    ,TO_DATE(AB,'YYYY-MM-DD') as Calendar_Date
    FROM job  A
   WHERE 
    ( A.O_DT <= TO_DATE(AB,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND ( A.C_DT IS NULL OR A.C_DT >= TO_DATE(AB,'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    AND A.S_CD IN ('010','110')
    AND NOT ( A.S_DT < TO_DATE(AB,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND A.S_CD IN ('110','120')) 
    )
       group by  TO_DATE(AB,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    LOOP
       AB := AB + 1;
       EXIT WHEN AB < dtill;
          dbms_output.put_line( o_cnt ||  Calendar_Date );
     END LOOP;
   END;

   Result would like 
   3000 2022-09-01
   3478 2022-09-02
   3895 2022-09-03
   3256 2022-09-04
   3145 2022-09-05
```

I have tried to create a statement like above, but it gives me error, I am sure I am missing something

Comment: Can someone help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put you select statement inside the loop and get the counts in a local variable for each increment of date. Eg.

```
declare
 dfrom date;
 dtill date;
 AB date;
 lv_opening_cnt number;
begin
  dfrom := TO_DATE('2022-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  dtill := TO_DATE('2022-09-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  AB := dfrom;
LOOP
 SELECT COUNT(A.HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID) 
   INTO lv_opening_cnt
 FROM WC_HRS_JOB_OPENING_F  A
 JOIN w_int_org_d BU on BU.row_wid = A.Business_unit_wid
 JOIN w_int_org_d DP on DP.row_wid = A.DEPTID_WID
 WHERE 
 ( A.OPEN_DT <= AB
 AND ( A.CLOSE_DT IS NULL OR A.CLOSE_DT >= AB)
 AND A.STATUS_CODE IN ('010','110')
 AND NOT ( A.STATUS_DT < AB) AND A.STATUS_CODE IN 
 ('110','120')) 
  )
 group by  AB;

  dbms_output.put_line( lv_openings_cnt ||  AB );
  AB := AB + 1;
  EXIT WHEN AB > dtill;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Hi Thank you again it is giving me error, however when executed with hardcoded values it is giving me value but not in above loop
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 11
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.

Comment: I edited the original post to remove to_date from AB since it is already a date variable. It should not give no data found error on line 11 since it is an aggregate function. It should return 0 where there is no record found.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much I am getting results now in DBMS output line, Can I load these values to a table ?

Comment: @Hippopottoman: Insert the list into a table? Well, create a table and instead of `dbms_output.put_line( lv_openings_cnt ||  AB );` do `insert into mytable values ( lv_openings_cnt ||  AB );` or `insert into mytable (cnt, dt) values ( lv_openings_cnt, AB );`